Error on VSCode on Ubuntu using my own font family and reset to default 'monospace'
While working on VSCode the font has suddenly changed to its default 'monospace' font. I searched and tried to solve this problem by following a lot of advice on Stack Overflow, but nothing was useful.
Here I changed the font to Operator Mono and JetBrains Mono fonts, but the result is the same:

Be sure every thing is going well:

From settings.json:


After some search, I found that fonts which aren't downloaded from Ubuntu's repositories are not identified by VSCode. So, I installed my preferred font by:

Before you install any fonts, be sure that the font doesn't exist on
your OS first by: /usr/share/fonts OR by type this command: fc-list | grep "Your font name"

sudo apt install fonts-jetbrains-mono
fc-cache -fv

If you already have the font and don't find it in the folder, you can move it by this command sudo mv "path of the font" /usr/share/fonts

/usr/share/fonts may be changed according to your distro.


I just had this problem and I discovered that I could not get a vscode that was installed as a Snap to pick up my personal fonts.  I solved the problem by uninstalling the code snap snap remove code and then downloading the code .deb file from the VS Code website.  The deb install of code picks up my personal fonts just fine.

Yeh, That's a good solution, but I wanted to protect my settings and extensions, so I search on a way to serve my needs. And thank you a lot for contributing

Your setting are stored in your home directory, not in the snap, removing the snap and installing as a deb will not change your settings or extensions.
